# How to select a tag

Tags: python, selenium

```
<a textcolor="inherit" value="2" href="/reports">
    <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorInherit" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab">
        <span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Reports</span>
        <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
    </button>
</a>
```

this is my frontend code. I want to select reports tab using this but not working

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/a[3]/button').click()
```

Comment: you had better to show  the complete html source or html url.

Comment: `not working` - please elaborate on what is wrong with the result.

Answer (score 0):

> you can try using the By method

> try to also skip '//*[@id="root"]'

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/a[3]/button').click()
```

> or in some cases ActionChains usually works for me too

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/[3]/button')
actions.click(on_element=element)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either go for `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` as explained by @Herker or go straight to the element by its class name, as there is only one element with `class='MuiTab-wrapper'`. Therefore, my proposal is:

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name("MuiTab-wrapper")
```

Either one can do the job